# Flask render image (and data)

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a very simple blog site, backed by Flask and the peewee orm. Only (markdown) posts and images. Images have the image file filed (obviously), a title and a brief description. I would like to be able to add a *filter* or *tag* or something and basically put in my markdown of the post something like `{{ img.id|3 }}` and have it render the image with the `id=3` in a `div`, with the title and description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use macros and Python functions to make that.

First, add a template global.

```
@app.template_global()
def get_image(id):
    # not sure if this is the way to do it with peewee
    return Image.select().where(Image.id == id).get()
```

This way, you can call `{{ get_image(id=3) }}` and get the image object. Of course, it still doesn't solve your problem.

To generate the HTML the way you want, create a Jinja2 macro to generate your HTML block.

```
{% macro img(id) %}
    {% set obj = get_image(id) %}  {# here I'm calling the template global function #}
    <img src="{{ obj.url }}" />
    <span class="title">{{ obj.title }}</span>
    <span class="description">{{ obj.description }}</span>
{% endmacro %}
```

Now, you can call `{{ img(id=3) }}` or even `{{ img(3) }}` to print the HTML from `img` macro.

Here I'm assuming your object with `url`, `title` and `description`. If you have a route to serve your images, maybe what you want is something like `url_for('some_route', id=id)` instead of `{{ obj.url }}`.

Of course you can serve the HTML from my `get_image` function or even query your database from my macro, but this way I separated concerns.

Comment: I can't display the image using this code. Is "3.jpg" must be located in the position?

Answer (score 1):

For Jinja2 you can add own filter with [`template_filter`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#registering-filters). Filters can take parameters.

If you already have image object in template with link properties, then better use this property.

If you have special route for this images, better use `url_for` with specified arguments. If it have many arguments you always can add custom filter.